# Write out variables in a loop to a dataset

Tags: sas

I want to assign a string to a variable in a loop and write out the variable to a dataset on each iteration.

Here is the code that prints out each variable

```
%macro t_size(inlib=,inds=);

   %let one_gig = 5000;

   proc sql noprint;
        select ceil((nobs*obslen)/&one_gig) into :tsize 
        from sashelp.vtable where libname=upcase("&inlib") and memname=upcase("&inds");
   quit;


   %let no_of_tables=%eval(%sysfunc(int(&tsize)));



   %if (&tsize gt 1) %then
      %do i = 1 %to &no_of_tables;
         %put &inds._&i.;
      %end;
   %else
      %do;
         %put &inds.;
      %end;

%mend;

%t_size(inlib=SASHELP,inds=SHOES);
run;
```

This produces the required output:

```
SHOES_1
SHOES_2
SHOES_3
SHOES_4
SHOES_5
SHOES_6
SHOES_7
```

Instead of printing the variables out to the log I want to write them to a new, empty dataset.

Comment: I don't understand the ask.  If you write something to a dataset it will not be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
%macro t_size(inlib=,inds=);

   %let one_gig = 5000;

   proc sql noprint;
        select ceil((nobs*obslen)/&one_gig) into :tsize 
        from sashelp.vtable where libname=upcase("&inlib") and memname=upcase("&inds");
   quit;


   %let no_of_tables=%eval(%sysfunc(int(&tsize)));


   data temp;
   length temp $100;
   %if (&tsize gt 1) %then
      %do i = 1 %to &no_of_tables;
         temp= "&inds._&i.";
         output;
      %end;
   %else
      %do;
         temp= "&inds.";
         output;
      %end;
   run;

%mend;

%t_size(inlib=SASHELP,inds=SHOES);
run;
```

Just add data step named `temp`, where input in variable `temp`.

**Output:**

```
+---------+
|  temp   |
+---------+
| SHOES_1 |
| SHOES_2 |
| SHOES_3 |
| SHOES_4 |
| SHOES_5 |
| SHOES_6 |
| SHOES_7 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are attempting to split a data set *FOO* into N *one_gig* pieces *FOO_1* to *FOO_N*.  Your first *step* also appears to be creating the FOO target table names.  Computing the split names within a DATA step will save the computed names.

Example:

```
%macro make_split_names(data=, out=split_names, splitsize=5000);

%local lib mem;
%let syslast = &data;
%let lib = %scan(&data,1,.);
%let mem = %scan(&data,2,.);

data parts;
  ds = open ('sashelp.cars');
  nobs = attrn(ds, 'NOBS');
  lrecl = attrn(ds, 'LRECL');
  ds = close(ds);

  do n = 1 to ceil ( nobs * lrecl / &splitsize );
    name = catx("_", "&mem", n);
    OUTPUT;
  end;

  keep name;
run;
%mend;


%make_split_names (data=sashelp.cars)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dataset then replace your last block of macro logic with a data step.

```
data member_list ;
   length memname $32 ;
   if &no_of_tables > 1 then do i=1 to &no_of_tables;
     memname=catx('_',"&inds",i);
     output;
   end;
   else do;
     memname="&inds";
     output;
   end;
   keep memname;
run;
```